# Passing array from CSV file in JMeter

Tags: arrays, csv, jmeter

I'm newbie in JMeter. Can anybody help me?

I need to passing array from my CSV file to my php function with JMeter.

ex :
in my CSV file

```
Data1
Data2
Data3
Data4
Data5
Data6
```

And can I do this?

```
{Data1, Data2, Data3} used by User1
{Data4, Data5, Data6} used by User2
```

How can I do that?

Please gimme a clue. I have been searching for the clues, but it's hard to found.

And sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit generic and not well defined.
I would recommend you view some JMeter video tutorials to get started and come back with more specific questions. These tutorial cover CSV files and dynamic JMeter requests so it also covers your specific question:

http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-tutorial-video-series

If you have questions after viewing the videos on something more specific come back elaborate on where you are stuck.